# Linux in VM - curl failing to download nvm file?

Tags: linux, curl

Trying to install nvm following the command from the website (curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash) and I get this error

```
=> Downloading nvm as script to '/home/ahmed/.nvm'
Failed to download 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/nvm-exec'
Failed to download 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/bash_completion'
Failed to download 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/nvm.sh'

=> nvm source string already in /home/ahmed/.bashrc
=> bash_completion source string already in /home/ahmed/.bashrc
main: line 433: /home/ahmed/.nvm/nvm.sh: No such file or directory
=> Close and reopen your terminal to start using nvm or run the following to use it now:

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up reinstalling the OS which fixed the problem

Answer (score 4):

It' related to a bug with snap version of curl. Try remove it and install curl with apt instead.

```bash
sudo snap remove curl
sudo apt install curl
```

Reference:
https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/2504#issuecomment-839570439

Answer (score 1):

It seems nvm is already installed, try to run it.

Comment: Yep did, no luck, the files weren't downloaded only the text added to the .bashrc

Comment: which OS is that? which source you got curl?, try to download the files manually and update.

Comment: Had same issue. `/home/ahmed/.nvm/nvm.sh: No such file or directory` clearly says `nvm.sh` file is not in the directory.